# angular chart pie-chart data click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-chart

Angular JS chart is awesome, But i need to implement click event in the piechart which i have created.. Here is the coding..

This is the JavaScript Coding...

```js
  $scope.pied = [{
          value: 4,
          color: "#FF5A5E",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: "Prospective"
        }, {
          value: 0,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#46BFBD",
          label: "Pending"
        }, {
          value: 0,
          color: "#FDB45C",
          highlight: "#FDB45C",
          label: "CallBacks"
        }, {
          value: 4,
          color: "#e6e6fa",
          highlight: "#e6e6fa",
          label: "FollowUp"
        }, {
          value: 1,
          color: "#cc5229",
          highlight: "#cc5229",
          label: "Not Interested"
        }, {
          value: 0,
          color: "#556b2f",
          highlight: "#556b2f",
          label: "Close"
        }]

        var pieOptions = {
          //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
          segmentShowStroke: true,

          //String - The colour of each segment stroke
          segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",

          //Number - The width of each segment stroke
          segmentStrokeWidth: 2,

          //Boolean - Whether we should animate the chart
          animation: true,

          //Number - Amount of animation steps
          animationSteps: 100,

          //String - Animation easing effect
          animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",

          //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Pie
          animateRotate: true,

          //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Pie from the centre
          animateScale: false,

          //Function - Will fire on animation completion.
          onAnimationComplete: null

        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie($scope.pied, pieOptions);
        ctx.onclick = function(evt){
        var activePoints = myPieChart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
        console.log("active: "+activePoints);
        // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
    };
        document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = myPieChart.generateLegend();
```

```html
This is the HTML Coding..
 <canvas id="pieChart" width="440" height="200" ></canvas>
   <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

This is the image of the above program.. i have wrote coding that when i click on The FollowUP it must the datas related to it.. But the click event is not working..??

[image]

Please see to the above code and picture and guide me to get the exact output what i expect. Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Used **angular-chart.js** instead this **chart.js** Angular JS Documentation is [here](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) . Angular Chart is little bit easy than chart.js..

Thanks for the support guys.. :)

Comment: does'nt understand the solution u used eventually, by using angular-chart

Comment: I was trying with chart.js to get the clicked contents, I can't get the contents by then. So, used angular-chart.js . I got output as expected. :)

Comment: with same code? interesting, it's more complex than the one in the examples of angular-chart

Comment: no the code above used in chart.js i used some easy codes from angular-chart.js and it worked :)